# Dagger 2 crash: "Cannot return null from a non-@Nullable @Provides method"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, exception, dagger-2

I haven't been able to recreate it myself. This is a crash that has shown up in Crashlytics by Fabric.

The line number points to this:
`App.getApp().getApplicationComponent().inject(this);`

I can't see where I'm going wrong.

'App' is an extension of the Application class that's in the manifest and working fine on the devices I test on. It is like this:

```
applicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
            .appModule(new AppModule(this))
...
...
            .netModule(new NetModule())
            .build();
```

The crashing fragment in question has the dependency marked with the @Inject annotation.

Here is a full stack trace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com....../com.....activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot return null from a non-@Nullable @Provides method
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3254)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot return null from a non-@Nullable @Provides method
   at dagger.internal.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:48)
   at com.....di.modules....Module_Provides...Factory.get(...Module_Provides...Factory.java:30)
   at com......di.modules....Module_Provides...Factory.get(...Module_Provides...Factory.java:10)
   at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
   at com.....fragments.HomeFragment_MembersInjector.injectMembers(HomeFragment_MembersInjector.java:39)
   at com.....fragments.HomeFragment_MembersInjector.injectMembers(HomeFragment_MembersInjector.java:9)
   at com.....di.DaggerApplicationComponent.inject(DaggerApplicationComponent.java:217)
   at com.....fragments.HomeFragment.onCreate(HomeFragment.java:87)
   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2068)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1055)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.setLastIn(BackStackRecord.java:838)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.calculateFragments(BackStackRecord.java:878)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:719)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1677)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:604)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1265)
   at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6915)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3217)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: So what is the thing you are trying to inject and is `null`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I don't know. The stack trace doesn't say and there are 2 dependencies, neither of which should be null. They both come from an Ormlite database.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce How do I make a class nullable? I tried running it and marking a `@Provides` method with `@Nullable` but it complained and said the class must be nullable. I marked it with `@Nullable` and that did nothing.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Still getting this crash where values shouldn't be null. I'm going to remove Dagger 2.

Comment: If you'll be getting `NPE` later by the same code, I'll be somewhat amused though.

Comment: I didn't. I removed Dagger 2, rewrote my classes and it worked fine without any crashes.

Comment: Interesting, what version of Dagger2 was this again?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce 2.7

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the same problem by returning a default object instead of null. My error started with the same Dagger message. I thought I could deal with null in the injected class. It makes a lot of sense to make all dependencies non-nullable as they can be part of other dependencies. It is very fundamental but of course while coding I didn't think of that.

```
@Provides
@Singleton
public FavCountry provideFavoriteCountry(RealmProvider realmProvider){

    FavCountry country = realmProvider.getRealm().where( FavCountry.class ).findFirst();

    //wait a minute, the table can be empty
    if( country == null ){
        country = new FavCountry("");
    }

    return country;
}
```